# scp a single file to multiple locations

Tags: linux, file-transfer, scp

Can you `scp` a file to multiple locations in the same command?

For example:

```
scp file.txt user@ip-1.com:, user@ip2.com:
```

Or would it be more practical to create a bash script that has all the hosts already in it and it would just take a file as the argument?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Let's say you have a file (`destfile.txt`) with `user@host`-values, one on each line. Then you could do like this:

```
while IFS= read -r dest; do
  scp ourfile.txt "$dest:remote/path/"
done <destfile.txt
```

Comment: This works!  Still a handful to type out though.  Perhaps there's a way to simplify that.

Comment: @Andrew, if you change the `for`-loop into `while read dest; do`, it will read from standard input. Put it in a script and feed the `destfile.txt` into it (e.g., `./thescript.sh <destfile.txt`).

Comment: I'm doing the former, but with rsync and some of my nodes are not updating. Any idea why?

Answer (score 9):

Looks like a job for parallel-scp[(n)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/parallel-scp.1.html)[(t)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/parallel-scp.1.html) - this implements a set of commands that allow for scp commands to be run on multiple systems at once. It will allow for the copying of files in parallel to a set of machines.

Answer (score 4):

```
cat file.txt | tee >(ssh user@ip1.com "cat > file.txt") \
                   >(ssh user@ip2.com "cat > file.txt")

tar cz file1 file2 file3 | tee >(ssh user@ip1.com "tar xz") \
                               >( ... )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a consistent naming convention going on for multiple servers, you can do something neat like:

```
for x in st1-abc-{11..20}.acme.com; do scp filez.tgz user@$x; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative (and a one-liner) would be to instead use pdsh to connect to each target node and trigger a get from there:

```
pdsh -w^destfile.txt scp hostname:/path/to/file /path/to/destfile
```

This of course requires one more information (the local host) and different user rights, but you avoid looping in bash and using indirection to read the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use xargs.

hosts.txt :

```
user@ip-1.com:
user@ip2.com:
```

Then run this command :

```
cat hosts.txt | xargs -I HOST scp file.txt HOST
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pssh or parallel-scp packages for ubuntu

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/parallel-scp.1.html
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/parallel-ssh.1.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, with a one line shell script.

```
cscp.sh 20337.patch < hosts.txt
```

It uses two files, one for the loop, and one for the server host list.
It reads `$1` for the first parameter from the CLI as the filename to SCP

*cscp.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
while read host; do
  scp $1 ${host}:
done
```

*hosts.txt*

```
project-prod-web1
project-prod-web2
project-prod-web3
```

*Usage*

Copy file to multiple hosts:

```
cscp.sh file < hosts
```